# C: performing signed comparison in unsigned variables without casting

Tags: c, casting, comparison, unsigned, signed

i want a function with the following signature:

```
bool signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(unsigned char a, unsigned char b);
```

its output should be `1` iff the 2's-complement view of the bits stored in `a` is greater than the 2's complement view of the bits stored in `b`. otherwise the output should be `0`. for example:

```
signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(0b10000000,any number) => 0
signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(0b01111111,any number other than 0b01111111) => 1
signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(0b00000000,0b00000001) => 0
signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(0b00000000,0b11111111) => 1
signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(0b00000000,0b00000000) => 0
```

the function is **not to have any implicit/explicit conversions** (as these conversions are 
implementation-defined, and thus not portable)

one such implementation is:

```
bool signed_a_greater_than_signed_b(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
    // if 'signed' a is positive then 
    //     return 1 if a is greater than b or b is negative
    // otherwise, if 'signed' a is negative then 
    //     return 1 if a is greater than b and b is negative
    if (a <= 0b01111111) return ((b < a) || (b > 0x01111111));
    else                 return ((b < a) && (b > 0x01111111));
}
```

can you suggest an implementation that uses arithmetic rather than conditionals to perform this calculations? you may use one condition if you must

using a mix of un/signed variables in comparisons and arithmetic in C is a recipe for disaster. this function is an example of how to circumvent the problem.

i guess the assembly behind comparison of signed variables is similar to the function i want to implement (on architectures not supporting signed comparisons)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming 2's complement:

```
return (a^signbit) > (b^signbit);
```

where `signbit` is obviously the MSB of the representation.

Comment: I assume you mean `(a^a_MSB) > (b^b_MSB)` in which case you are comparing the absolute values of `a` and `b`

Comment: @random guy, I'm not sure what you mean by a_MSB.  I intend *toggling* (and not clearing) the sign bit.  If you put the numbers on a circle, that just change the origin and so does  to a signed comparison.  BTW as an alternative to xoring, you can use adding if the MSB of the representation is the MSB of the type used and promotions aren't involved (i.e that will work with unsigned int, not unsigned char).

Answer (score 0):

> you may use one condition if you must

You already have a solution using only one condition. ;)

As you would like to have arithmetic operations rather than conditionals, I assume that the goal is speed. And using a look-up table is even faster than arithmetic. Because you are using 8 bit chars, a look-up table means no overkill: You don't even need a table of size 256x256. A table size of 256 is perfectly adequate storing a limit for each value of `a` indicating the value(s) `b` may have to result in true (or false). Each function call only needs to perform one table look-up (`a` -> `limit`) and one comparison (`limit` <> `b`).